# Error executions Workflow install Cloudify

Tags: cloudify

I'm trying to run a workflow in cloudify, but when running the command:

```
cfy executions start -w install -d teste003 --debug --include-logs
```

The following error occurs below:

```
Execution of workflow 'install' for deployment 'teste003' timed out. * Run 'cfy executions cancel --execution-id c12ac2b2-fd34-4a04-a4bc-252871f9e166' to cancel the running workflow.
* Run 'cfy events list --tail --include-logs --execution-id c12ac2b2-fd34-4a04-a4bc-252871f9e166' to retrieve the execution's events/logs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/cloudify/bin/cfy", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('cloudify==3.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'cfy')()
  File "/home/ubuntu/cloudify/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify_cli/cli.py", line 37, in main
    args.handler(args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cloudify/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify_cli/cli.py", line 143, in command_cmd_handler
    command['handler'](**kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cloudify/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify_cli/commands/executions.py", line 174, in start
    raise SuppressedCloudifyCliError()
SuppressedCloudifyCliError
```

Below my file aws-ec2-blueprint.yaml:

```
tosca_definitions_version: cloudify_dsl_1_1

imports:
  - http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/cloudify/3.2.1/types.yaml
  - http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/aws-plugin/1.2.1/plugin.yaml
  - http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/diamond-plugin/1.2.1/plugin.yaml

inputs:

  image:
    description: >
      Image to be used when launching agent VM's

  size:
    description: >
      Flavor of the agent VM's

  agent_user:
    description: >
      User for connecting to agent VM's

node_templates:

  mongod_host:
    type: cloudify.aws.nodes.Instance
    properties:
      image_id: { get_input: image }
      instance_type: { get_input: size }
```

My inputs.yaml:

image: ami-d05e75b8

size: m3.medium

agent_user: ubuntu

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know why the install timed out without seeing the logs of the install.

In most cases it is related to the connection to the spawned VM or an install process that keep failing.

I would try to check:

- AWS permissions to spawn a VM and connect to it
- Security groups, port 22 open to the manager VM
- Internet access of the spawned VM